# Uptade Sheet.("print") and Export to single pdf

Tags: excel, vba

I built an loop which update the Sheet("print").

Every time that this sheet uptades I have to print/export it to and PDF file.

Is possible to print/export several time the same sheet to an single PDF?

```
'Loop
For i = 4 To lastrow
    If Planilha4.Range("B" & i).Value = Empty Then GoTo continua
        If Planilha4.Range("J" & i).Value = Range("cart_ref_tipo_cartaz").Value Then
            Range("imp_linha").Value = i - 3
            **'I'm currently printing it to Fine Print**
            PlanilhaA4.PrintOut Copies:=Range("imp_copias").Value, IgnorePrintAreas:=False           
        End If
    End If
continua: 
Next i
```

Comment: You want to print the same sheet more than once on the same PDF?

Comment: @RicardoA, exactly

I tried the code below, but it creates several PDFs.

` PlanilhaA4.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
            ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Temp\" & Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY"), Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True `

Comment: In the answer I entered. Only change 2 things, The sheet name "Testing" to yours, and the Filename, leave everything else the same and try it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to print to PDF the same sheet, more than one time on the same PDF, is to copy the sheet and print/save them. Code below tested in Excel 2016/365. If your excel creates a new WB with 3 Sheets, delete all 3 instead of just one like i did.

```
Sub printSheet()
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    'The next line creates a new Workbook
    Set newWB = Workbooks.Add
    'The next line creates a copy of Sheet "Testing" on the new Workbook
    wb.Sheets("Testing").Copy newWB.Sheets(newWB.Sheets.Count)
    'Delete the empty Default Sheet1 from the new WB
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    newWB.Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'Create two Copies of Testing to print three.
    newWB.Sheets("Testing").Copy newWB.Sheets(newWB.Sheets.Count)
    newWB.Sheets("Testing").Copy newWB.Sheets(newWB.Sheets.Count)
    'Save to PDF
    'Unfurtonately, you have to use ActiveSheet to print to PDF, so we have to use Activate and Select to print both sheets.
    newWB.Activate
    newWB.Sheets(Array(newWB.Worksheets(1).Name, newWB.Worksheets(2).Name, newWB.Worksheets(3).Name)).Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\username\Documents\filename.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
    'close new WB
    newWB.Close False
End Sub
```